# How can I use Trello with contexts, as with GTD?

Tags: trello

I've been using Trello for quite a while and love the project-/board-based approach to task management.  However, my lifestyle has made it necessary to make use of context-based task filtering so that when I find time at home after work to do some things I can quickly see what I have that needs to be done at home, for example.

I thought I could use labels for this purpose, which seemed to work okay searching across multiple boards, but since some of my boards are used by teams that actually make use of labels themselves, that didn't seem like a good solution; there was label pollution, if you will.  I was thinking I could also just come up with my own keywords to put in the description, like "context--home", "context--work".  Whatever the solution is, it needs to work at least as well on Android as it does on a desktop browser.  I guess that rules out a search-based solution though as Android search isn't really implemented yet.

Any other ideas?  Maybe integration with another Android app?

Comment: I have the same dilemma. Trello now supports custom labels so that may be a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I use the "Agile SCRUM for Trello boards" Chrome extension. I can use custom tags in the cards' titles like [home_pc], [phone] or [car]. These are global, meaning that you do not have to pollute all boards with the same labels.

Other useful chrome extensions I found useful for implementing my flavor of GTD are "Full screen card view for Trello", "Kanban WIP for Trello" and "Snapshot for Trello".